# GridControl keeps throwing an invalid path exception

Tags: c#, database, gridview, devexpress, ms-access-2010

So i am using XtraGrid component from DevExpress, set up the connection, the preview (in design tome) actually shows the content of my database table, in runtime, i manage to catch this exception, which shows that the path set for the database is wrong, because i don't remember putting a wrong path neither remember the preview giving an error.
[image]
This is the line where it throws the error

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.fournisseursTableAdapter.Fill(this.maindbDataSet.Fournisseurs); //Catches exception here
    xtraTabControl1.ShowTabHeader = DefaultBoolean.False;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
 }
```

Comment: How did you specify the connection string?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten i used the wizard that came with the control, so no code required to specify the path, etc... Just 3 more objects dropped into my form. [Link](http://imgur.com/a/Sv3dD)

Comment: What do you have in App.config?

Comment: The wrong paths, thanks man, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the App.config file has that wrong path. Check the file to correct the path.